# My partitions are messed up and I don't know how to fix them

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, hard-drive, kde, volume-control

Storage has always been tight for me on my Lenovo laptop running Kubuntu (no dual booting, just Kubuntu). I have always thought that I have 233 GB of usable storage.

But yesterday, I have opened my laptop up to upgrade the RAM and I discovered that the HDD inside is 1 TB.

So, I ran the following command and sure enough, the OS sees that HDD:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And the result is as follows: (after removing all snap loop volumes)

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: LENSE30256GMSP34MEAT3TA                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3235924C-672D-45A7-AFC1-A0EF35F3F7AE

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: 236.102 GiB, 254472617984 bytes, 497016832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The result of `sudo df -h` is as follows: (again after removing snap's loop volumes)

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         3.2G  1.8M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root  233G  200G   21G  91% /
tmpfs                          16G  139M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1                511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                         3.2G   20K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

In `"KDE Partition Manager"` I can also see the 1 TB volume and I can create new partion table on it. The problem is that I'm terrified of losing all my data and configurations if I do so.

**My question is, how can I expand my root volume so that I can use the whole HDD?**

Here are 3 screenshots from `"KDE Partition Manager"`

(1)
[image: Screenshot2]
(2)
[image: Screenshot2]
(3)
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: @user535733 I have a backup of my data. But restoring the development environment is a big hassle that I don't want to go into

Comment: @user535733 sadly, no. I have come across this link while searching. My current logical volume appears as if it's not part of the physical device. If it's a matter of just allocating and resizing the partition, it's a simple matter to me as I have done it many times before. But as you can see in my 3rd screenshot, I have only 24 MB of unallocated space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see TWO hardware items in your output:

Here's one, your SSD, which includes your Ubuntu system:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: LENSE30256GMSP34MEAT3TA                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3235924C-672D-45A7-AFC1-A0EF35F3F7AE

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux LVM
```

Here's the other, which seems to be unpartitioned and is unused:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Advice: Partition the HDD and start using it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You mean that I have 2 physical devices? But when I opened my laptop to upgrade the RAM, I saw only 1 hard drive inside. Is it possible that the SSD drive integrated in the motherboard?

Comment: I was not there when you opened the case. I can only help you interpret your output. NVME SSDs can be very small, and often do not look like disks.

Comment: You are right. I have partitioned the HDD and it is usable without any issues